# Previous and Next buttons are displayed on new lines with jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is happening in Opera 11, Firefox 3.6.13, and IE 8. On all of the datepickers I create the previous and next buttons are being displayed on their own line above the month and year. This happens in both my custom rolled theme, and using UI Lightness which I downloaded fresh and has no custom CSS added. I am using jQuery UI version 1.8.9 and jQuery 1.4.3. I have reproduced it on jsFiddle using UI 1.8.7 and jQuery 1.4.4 as well.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bkress/R8YEa/)

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dates = $('.date').datepicker();
});
```

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body class="ui-widget">
        <div id='mainApplication' class="ui-widget">
            <div id="menuBar" class="ui-widget">
                <br />
                <span><strong>Start Date:</strong></span><br>
                <input type="text" id="start" class="date"><br>
                <span><strong>End Date:</strong></span><br>   
                <input type="text" id="end" class="date"><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a css problem. If you compare the  css(using firebug) of the [demo example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and what you have written  you will see that the css is different. If you add the css file "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" by URL through "Add Resources" you will get the correct layout.

Comment: Found it thank you. Somehow my download of the CSS from the theme roller was missing the set of definitions for the datepicker. A fresh download making sure I selected the correct bits fixed this.